# Programa en Java que obtenga la sumatoria de la serie: 4 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + ... para n términos

Tags: java

¿Como se hace para que en la serie se intercalen los signos?

Comment: bienvenido, favor de leer [ask], la idea de la comunidad es apoyar en dudas puntuales de código, por lo tanto no solo es necesario indicar que deseas obtener sino además que llevas hecho o investigado

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int base = 4;
    int divisor = 1;
    String fraccion = "";
    char operador = '+';

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fraccion = operador + "" + base + "/" + divisor;
        System.out.print(fraccion + " ");
        divisor += 2;
        operador = operador == '+' ? '-' : '+';
    }
}
```

Salida

> +4/1 -4/3 +4/5 -4/7 +4/9 -4/11 +4/13 -4/15 +4/17 -4/19